# Explorer.exe stopped working

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer

I assume some files have been corrupted, with `chkdsk /f /r` returning no disk errors, as every 5s I receive InPageError `c000009c` and `00000003`.

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: Can we see some error messages?

Answer (score 1):

> Explorer.exe stopped working

**(A) Update ALL Drivers** (Computer Manufacturer's Driver Update App. Also run Manufacturer’s Diagnostics.

**(B) Then**, run DISM and SFC as easy repairs to see if this fixes the issue.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(C) Third:** if (B) did not resolve the issue run Windows 10 Repair Install (Assuming this is Windows 10 or 11)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> (Change 10 to 11 if Windows 11)
>
> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Comment: It may be worth running Windows Memory Diagnostic too.

Comment: Yes I agree - noted